# Pick two different items randomly from an array

Tags: arrays, ruby, random

In a fighting program, I have two players in an array:

```
players = [brad, josh]
```

I want to randomly select two distinct players, one of which will attack the other, schematically like this:

```
random_player.attack(other_random_player)
```

I want to make sure that the players never attack themselves. If I do:

```
players[rand(0..1)].attack(players[rand(0..1)])
```

there is a chance one player will fight itself. How do I make it so once the first player is chosen and fights the remaining player(s) from the array?

Comment: This is a little confusing. You said you have two players in an array and then that you'd like to randomly select two distinct players (rather than saying that you'd like to select one as attacker and the other as defender). @sawa interpreted that literally; the others offering answers assumed the array could be larger. Also, the contents of `players` should be symbols or strings. `brad` is not a Ruby object unless you mean it to be a method, which I doubt.

Answer (score 10):

You could use `.sample`:

```
match = players.sample(2);
match[0].attack(match[1]);
```

This will randomly pick two players from the array, then you have them fight each other.  There is no way the same player will be picked for both.

More cleanly:

```
p1, p2 = players.sample(2)
p1.attack p2
```

Comment: This is one of those questions that has only one good answer, and this is it. It might be clearer if you wrote `p1, p2 = players.sample(2)`, then `p1.attack p2`. You don't need the semi-colons.

Comment: @CarySwoveland - good call, I haven't written any ruby in a while and it shows

Answer (score 1):

```
attacker, attackee = players.shuffle
attacker.atack(attackee)
```

Comment: "attackee" is a nice touch.

Comment: I think defender is much more appropriate =)

Answer (score 0):

This is a good use case for a [Set](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.3/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html) for a few reasons:

1. Players are unique
2. The order of the elements makes no difference
3. You're instantly protected if you mistakenly try to add the same player twice to the Set.

Here's an example:

```
set = Set.new
set << player1
set << player2
set.to_a.sample(2)
```

Answer (score -2):

You could do something like this:

```
players.delete_at(rand(players.length)).attack(players.sample)
```

That way it will remove 1 player from the array every time. That will work if you have more than 2 players as well, and want one of the players to attack a random other player.

Or you could just do this if you only will have 2 players:

```
players.delete_at(rand(players.length)).attack(players[0])
```

Comment: What you have is equivalent to `p1 = players.sample; p2 = players.sample; p1.attack p2`. That does not prevent `p1` and `p2` from being the same player.

Comment: "remove 1 player from the array" is not something `Array#sample` does.